# Identify this insect seen in a rural area in North India

Tags: species-identification, entomology

During my stay at a village in Haryana, India, I noticed many of these grey-brown insects in my room. They spend most of their time crawling but occasionally fly too (for short distances—one metre to a few metres). Here are some photographs—the spacing between the ruled lines is about 7 mm:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am curious to know what species they are. Any help would be appreciated.